# Error adding repository nilarimogard/webupd8

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, repository

I am having problem with any repository that I try to add in order to install some program. In the case below, I tried to add the repository with the following command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 -y
```

in order to install the WoeUSB program.

The error output was as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 335, in get_ppa_info
    ret = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 92, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_lp(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 110, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 153, in urlopen
    capath=capath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 470, in create_default_context
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath, cadata)
ssl.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:3053)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 122, in <module>
    shortcut = shortcut_handler(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 864, in shortcut_handler
    ret = factory(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 407, in shortcut_handler
    return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 364, in __init__
    info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 347, in get_ppa_info
    _get_suggested_ppa_message(user, ppa))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 304, in _get_suggested_ppa_message
    lp_user = get_info_from_lp(LAUNCHPAD_USER_API % user)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 110, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 153, in urlopen
    capath=capath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 470, in create_default_context
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath, cadata)
ssl.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:3053)
```

My operating system is Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.

If someone can tell me what is wrong in my repositories and how to fix it I will be very grateful.

Also, I can not install anything by the central Ubuntu, the program begins to install and without giving any warning of something that went wrong.

**UPDATE**

This is output from my `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
E: Não foi possível obter trava /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Recurso temporariamente indisponível)
E: Impossível criar acesso exclusivo ao directório /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-pt_BR) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-pt) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
```

Comment: Is your server CA certificate store in working order?  Make sure you can connect to SSL protected sites from your server.

Comment: As I do to verify this? I'm sorry if it's something obvious.

Comment: What does `sudo apt-get update` output?